# azure devops - define build and release order

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I do have multiple builds watching the same repository / branch. Is there a way to define the order for executing the builds / releases? It's possible to define a trigger when a build completes, start another one, but this method can't run builds in parallel. It's ok, if I could define the order for the releases. I've been searching for, but could not find a way to achieve this. Is it possible?

Comment: For release you should create a separate environments where you can perform release one after another envi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the order of executing builds (CI) and releases (CD).

### To define order of build

---

If you want to define the execution of CI build, the easiest way to do that is by using YAML and use the multi jobs model. Then arrange each job to depends on other job to be finished first.

For example:

```
jobs:
- job: JOB1
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "hello from vmImage vs2017-win2016"
      echo "compile webnoauth.csproj using VS2017"

  - task: MSBuild@1
    displayName: Build WebFormsNoAuth.csproj
    inputs:
      solution: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\aspnetfx\ASPNET.WebForms.v4.7.2\ASPNET.WebForms.v4.7.2.sln
      msbuildLocationMethod: version
      msbuildVersion: '15.0'
      configuration: "Release"
      msbuildArguments: /nologo /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile2
      clean: 'false'
      maximumCpuCount: 'false'

  - script: |
      echo "copy result to staging"
      xcopy $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\aspnetfx\ASPNET.WebForms.v4.7.2\WebFormsNoAuth\bin\Release\Publish $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) /E
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1

- job: JOB2
  dependsOn: JOB1
  pool:
    vmImage: 'win1803'
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "hello from vmImage win1803"
      md buildresult
      echo "copy buildresult into build folder"
      xcopy $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) buildresult /E
      echo "begin build docker image"

- job: JOB3
  dependsOn: JOB2
  pool:
    vmImage: 'win1803'
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Other job to be run in JOB 3"
```

For more information on YAML multi jobs, it's documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/multiple-phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops

### To define order of release

---

Simply arrange the order of the release by ensuring continuation of the release stage (it is called *environment* in Azure DevOps Pipelines term). Usually, the visualization starts from left to right, that looks like a flow.

For example, you may have order arrangements of releases of Dev, SIT, Production.

[image: release order sample]

The official documentation for the stage arrangement on Azure DevOps Pipelines is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops#extend-a-release-pipeline-by-adding-stages

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the build order, you can find [some tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=%22queue%20build%22&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) in the Marketplace to trigger/queue a new build, such as the [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks):

> Build Task that can be used to trigger a new Build so that
>   build-chaining is possible. Supports as well conditional triggers.

Current version of the task (V3) looks like this:

[image: Trigger Build screenshot]

For example,suppose you want to run the following builds in this particular order:

1. B1
2. B2

B1 would be triggered whenever the code changes (continuous integration) and the last task of the build would be the one I mentioned above, to trigger build B2. B2 would be set as a manual build.

Comment: The asker want to have builds ordered in sequences, therefore the next sequence will be triggered automatically if the previous sequence is built successfully. The trigger task is useful to chain builds, but it mainly doesn't really care about the actual order/sequence.